# Maintaining a local Arch repository

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, repository

I maintain a number of non-internet connect computers which are running Arch Linux. I find it helpful to create a local repository that partially mirrors the typical Arch repositories. I keep this repository on a USB drive which I use to update the computers by making the appropriate changes to `pacman.conf`. I create the repository by generating a `ListOfPackages` which contains the names of all the *packages* (or package groups) that have been directly installed on the computers, but not packages that are pulled in as dependencies. The USB drive is mounted at /mnt. I then do

```
sudo pacman --dbpath /tmp --noconfirm -Syw ${ListOfPackages} --cachedir /mnt

for package in /mnt/*.pkg.tar.xz; do
  gpg --batch --yes -sb ${package}
  repo-add -v -s -q strongbad.db.tar.gz ${package}
done
```

which generates the `strongbad` repository. The problem comes when it is time to update the repository. Typically I just delete everything and start over to avoid keeping old versions and now unneeded dependencies, but this is a big waste of bandwidth. Is there a good way to update the packages and repository that minimizes the number of packages downloaded and cleans out cruft?

Comment: Look at [pacserv](https://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/pacserve/) and then just use `-Sc` or `paccache` to maintain the cache.